# JxBrowser memory footprint: handling DOM leaks

Tags: memory, jxbrowser

We are using Vaadin as our back end technology.

Vaadin clients consume browser memory due to DOM leaks.

The memory consumed by the browser eventually leads to performance issues.

**Questions**:

1. Is there a way to monitor the Browser instance for memory consummation or performance deterioration?
2. Is there a way to dynamically restart the Browser instance without impacting the client, or limit the impact on the user experience?

Similar to:
[JxBrowser takes huge RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246831/jxbrowser-takes-huge-ram/39270528#39270528)

Answer (score 0):

1. At the moment, JxBrowser doesn't provide such functionality.
2. Well, if we are talking about "restarting" the Browser instance, I can suggest that you just dispose it and create a new Browser instance. It's like closing and opening a new tab in Google Chrome. Af far as I know, at the moment Chromium doesn't provide functionality that allows "restarting" the Browser instance without reloading already loaded web page and destroying session cookies.